# На фото - мусорный горшочек: как он называется?

Tags: выбор-слов, названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называется это вместилище отходов? Мусорный бак, мусорная корзина?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это уличная **урна** для мусора. *Мусорной корзиной* называют небольшую ёмкость для *бумажных* отходов, обычно в офисе; в домашних условиях это *мусорное ведро*, а случайную или временную емкость для мусора именуют *мусорницей* или неформально "мусоркой". "Бак" - это *крупное* уличное вместилище мусора, который периодически вывозят.

Comment: Хотел плюс поставить, но остановила моя нелюбимая "мусорка".))) И всё же поставлю.

Comment: Это новое для меня слово "мусорница" звучит похоже на "сахарницу". :)

Answer (score 6):

По-моему, это обычная ***урна***.

Уж никак это не мусорный бак — пластиковый или металлический кубоид объёмом где-то от 1000 л, обычный для помоек, куда все мусор выносят.